# I want multiple click on button in for loop jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.carousel_ul').on("click", "li", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var index = $(this).index();
        //alert(index);
        for(var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            $('#right_scroll img').click();
        }

    });
```

I am facing an issue when `$('#right_scroll img').click()` is clicked only one time but I want to click it as per the condition in `for` loop.

Comment: try .trigger('click') instead of .click. For some reason sometimes the trigger one works better   --also if that doesnt work make a JSFiddle to assist us

Comment: What's the code look like inside of the `$('#right_scroll img').click()` handler? This is going to execute extremely fast. It may be possible depending on the handler that the function is executing properly but the results are not visible or are overridden due to the inherently fast nature of these click events within the `for` loop.